# Flair Framework with PyTorch - OverflowError: int too big to convert

Tags: python, pytorch, flair

I'm trying to train a named entity recognition model with Flair Framework (https://github.com/flairNLP/flair), with this embedding: `TransformerWordEmbeddings('emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT')`. However, it always failed with `OverflowError: int too big to convert`. This is also happening in some other transformer word embedding such as `XLNet`. However, `BERT` and `RoBERTa` works fine.

Here is the full traceback of the error:

```
2021-04-15 09:34:48,106 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-04-15 09:34:48,106 Corpus: "Corpus: 778 train + 259 dev + 260 test sentences"
2021-04-15 09:34:48,106 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-04-15 09:34:48,106 Parameters:
2021-04-15 09:34:48,106  - learning_rate: "0.1"
2021-04-15 09:34:48,106  - mini_batch_size: "32"
2021-04-15 09:34:48,106  - patience: "3"
2021-04-15 09:34:48,106  - anneal_factor: "0.5"
2021-04-15 09:34:48,106  - max_epochs: "200"
2021-04-15 09:34:48,106  - shuffle: "True"
2021-04-15 09:34:48,106  - train_with_dev: "False"
2021-04-15 09:34:48,106  - batch_growth_annealing: "False"
2021-04-15 09:34:48,107 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-04-15 09:34:48,107 Model training base path: "/home/xxx/data/xxx-clinical-bert"
2021-04-15 09:34:48,107 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-04-15 09:34:48,107 Device: cuda:0
2021-04-15 09:34:48,107 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-04-15 09:34:48,107 Embeddings storage mode: gpu
2021-04-15 09:34:48,116 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_medical_2.py", line 144, in <module>
    train_ner(d + '-base-ent',corpus_base)
  File "train_medical_2.py", line 136, in train_ner
    max_epochs=200)
  File "/home/d111199102201607101/flair/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flair/trainers/trainer.py", line 381, in train
    loss = self.model.forward_loss(batch_step)
  File "/home/d111199102201607101/flair/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flair/models/sequence_tagger_model.py", line 637, in forward_loss
    features = self.forward(data_points)
  File "/home/d111199102201607101/flair/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flair/models/sequence_tagger_model.py", line 642, in forward
    self.embeddings.embed(sentences)
  File "/home/d111199102201607101/flair/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flair/embeddings/token.py", line 81, in embed
    embedding.embed(sentences)
  File "/home/d111199102201607101/flair/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flair/embeddings/base.py", line 60, in embed
    self._add_embeddings_internal(sentences)
  File "/home/d111199102201607101/flair/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flair/embeddings/token.py", line 923, in _add_embeddings_internal
    self._add_embeddings_to_sentence(sentence)
  File "/home/d111199102201607101/flair/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flair/embeddings/token.py", line 999, in _add_embeddings_to_sentence
    truncation=True,
  File "/home/d111199102201607101/flair/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py", line 2438, in encode_plus
    **kwargs,
  File "/home/d111199102201607101/flair/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_fast.py", line 472, in _encode_plus
    **kwargs,
  File "/home/d111199102201607101/flair/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_fast.py", line 379, in _batch_encode_plus
    pad_to_multiple_of=pad_to_multiple_of,
  File "/home/d111199102201607101/flair/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_fast.py", line 330, in set_truncation_and_padding
    self._tokenizer.enable_truncation(max_length, stride=stride, strategy=truncation_strategy.value)
OverflowError: int too big to convert
```

I have tried to change the `embedding_storage_mode`, `hidden_size`, and `mini_batch_size`. None of these gave me the fix to the issue.

Does anyone have the same issue?
Is there any way to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you managed to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below parameters to limit the length of tokens

```
embedding = TransformerWordEmbeddings('emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT')
embedding.max_subtokens_sequence_length = 512
embedding.stride = 512//2
```